# Error messages doesn't show up in my JSP

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, interceptor

Hi i have a problem in my app, my jsp doesn't show error messages.

i don't realy understand this code in my jsp :

```
<s:if test="hasActionMessages()">
   <div class="message">
      <s:actionmessage/>
   </div>
</s:if>

<s:if test="hasFieldErrors()">
   <div class="errors">
      <s:fielderror />
   </div>
</s:if>
```

i don't understand `hasActionMessages()` & `hasFieldErrors()`
are they defined some where?

Comment: This methods are in `ActionSupport` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Errors and messages are used in [validation](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation.html) via [`validation` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/validation-interceptor.html). The code above checks if there  action messages or field errors on the value stack.

The action should implement `WalidationAware` to get these methods `hasActionMessages()` and `hasFieldErrors()` available to the OGNL. You don't need to implement it if your action extends `ActionSupport`. There's already implemented these methods.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you have tried but this will help you 
[Struts 2 ActionError & ActionMessage Example](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-actionerror-actionmessage-example/)
[workflow-interceptor](http://www.javatpoint.com/struts-2-custom-validation-workflow-interceptor)
[Working With Struts 2 Theme & Template](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/)

Comment: ,thanks  i will check this links,by the way i'm trying this link http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/struts2liferay-service-builder-jqgrid.html